# Indefinite integral evaluation

Tags: integration

Could you please give me some hint on how to integrate the below. I have tried substitution methods but I am unable to arrive at the conclusion

$$I=\int \dfrac {{(x^8 + 4)^{\frac {1}{3}} }}{{ 3x^2}} dx$$

Comment: Who gave you this problem? Put it in Wolfram Alpha and see that the answer is not nice looking, involving an "$F_1$" ,a Gaussian hypergeometric function.

Comment: Would that mean there is an error in the question? or will it involve complex steps, unlike traditional integral calculation?

Comment: Most likely there is an error, if you have picked this out of some textbook with class 11/12 integration. If you picked this out from a book which contained hypergeometric integrals, then this question is not a printing mistake, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, there is a serious problem with this integral.

If you do not want to face hypergeometric functions, make a series expansion
$$I=\int \dfrac {{(x^8 + 4)^{\frac {1}{3}} }}{{ 3x^2}} dx=\frac{2^{5/12}}{3}\int \frac{(t^8 + 1)^{\frac {1}{3}}}{t^2} dt$$

$$I=\frac{2^{5/12}}{3}\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{1}{3}}{n} t^{8 n-2}\,dt=\frac{2^{5/12}}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{1}{3}}{n}\frac{t^{8 n-1}}{8 n-1}$$ the summation corresponding to
$$-\frac{1}{t}\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{8};\frac{7}{8};-t^8\right)$$